# Quitar corchetes de la vista en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy trayendo el último registro de la base de datos y mostrar el número del id.

**Controlador**

```
$ultimaterifa = Rifa::select('id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
 return back()->with('mensaje', 'Su número de rifa es: '. $ultimaterifa);
```

El problema es que en la vista el mensaje me lo muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo quiero mostrar el número.

El código de la vista es:

```
@if ( session('mensaje') )
      <div class="alert alert-success">{{ session('mensaje') }}</div>
    @endif
```

Comment: Buen día, si sólo quieres el `id` agrega `->pluck('id')` a la consulta, después de `first()`

Answer (score 1):

En laravel esta el metodo [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-pluck)

Con este metodo a partir de un array permite retornar los datos correspondiente a una llave:

***Ejemplo de la documentacion:***

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
    ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
]);
 
$plucked = $collection->pluck('name');
 
$plucked->all();
 
// ['Desk', 'Chair']
```

**Nota:** en este caso al existir varios nodos dentro de la coleccion con la llave `name` el metodo se le agrega `all` retornara un array con todo, esto te ayudara a iterar en consultas con multiples registros.

En tu caso en donde solo estas trabajando con un registro y la colleccion solo tiene una llave no requiere agregar el `all`

Comment: La consulta de OP que finaliza en `->first()` le va a devolver un modelo eloquent, no una coleccion

Comment: pasame la documentacion, eso no lo vi XD

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models. Dejeje un comentario debajo de la pregunta. Creo que lo mas secillo ahi seria acceder directamente a la propiedad `->id` del modelo

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ pero no me queda claro por que funciona ... el objeto eloquent puede ser entonces trabajado como una colleccion???

Comment: Cierto, tambien me sorprende. De alguna manera parece que pluck funciona con un modelo, sin embargo por lo que estoy probando [aqui](https://phpsandbox.io/n/lavender-mace-windu-nlvf1#routes/web.php) devuelve una coleccion con los ids de todos los modelos, no solo el de la consulta

Comment: si ya la veo eso en RTL??

Comment: Esta raro... no se supone que para eso esta el `first()` agarara el primero del modelo?

Comment: El el [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/lavender-mace-windu-nlvf1#routes/web.php) que lo estoy probando, `\App\Models\User::first()->pluck('id')` me devuelve una coleccion con los elementos desordenados  `[2,1,4,5,6,10,3,9,8,7]`. No se a que te refieres con RTL... right to left?

Comment: a no que si se puede ver los cambios que haces en tiempo real ...

Comment: Ahh, para modificarlo en el sandbox tendrias que hacerte un fork, creo que no puedes modificarlo si no lo generaste con tu usuario

Comment: ha ok esta bueno el sandbox, yo suelo pasar de preguntas complejas que no se puedan responder desde la documentacion por no tener donde demostrar cosas, como estas ...

Comment: pero de paso puedes agregar tu respuesta me parece valida y que incluyas lo que has encontrado ...

Comment: Vale, ahora escribo una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Para responder rápidamente a la pregunta... Con tu consulta:

```
$ultimaterifa = Rifa::select('id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Vas a obtener una instancia del model `Rifa` (como esta explicado en la documentacion [Retrieving Single Models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)). Por lo que podrías simplemente acceder a su propiedad `id` para **solo mostrar el numero** `$ultimaterifa->id`:

```
return back()->with('mensaje', 'Su número de rifa es: '. $ultimaterifa->id);
```

---

Ahora, nada que ver con la pregunta, pero agrego dado el descubrimiento que hicimos con @FranciscoNuñezIALover en su respuesta. Nos encontramos con un comportamiento inesperado al aplicar la funcion `pluck()` sobre un modelo Eloquent.

```
Rifa::select('id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->pluck('id');
```

Uno esperaría que lance una excepción, sin embargo no lo hace, en cambio devuelve una colección con la ids de todas las filas correspondientes a ese modelo:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1276 ▼ // resources/views/welcome.blade.php
  #items: array:10 [▼
    0 => 2
    1 => 1
    2 => 4
    3 => 5
    4 => 6
    5 => 10
    6 => 3
    7 => 9
    8 => 8
    9 => 7
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Aquí un phpsandbox donde lo probamos con el modelo `User`: https://phpsandbox.io/n/lavender-mace-windu-nlvf1#routes/web.php

Nada, esto último solo como una curiosidad que no nos esperábamos.

Comment: con esto afirmo que dos cabezas piensan mejor que una, gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Excelente, pienso lo mismo. Y gracias por la edicion tambien